# Using device variable by multiple threads on CUDA

Tags: cuda, race-condition

I am playing around with cuda.

At the moment I have a problem. I am testing a large array for particular responses, and when I get the response, I have to copy the data onto another array.

For example, my test array of 5 elements looks like this: 
[ ][ ][v1][ ][ ][v2]

Result must look like this: 
[v1][v2]

The problem is how do I calculate the address of the second array to store the result? All elements of the first array are checked in parallel.

I am thinking to declare a device variable int *addr* = 0. Every time I find a response, I will increment the *addr*. But I am not sure about that because it means that *addr* may be accessed by multiple threads at the same time. Will that cause problems? Or will the thread wait until another thread finishes using that variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not as trivial as it seems. I just finished to implement one and I can tell what you need
read the [scan Gpu Gems 3 Article](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html) in particular chapter **39.3.1 Stream Compaction**.

To implement your own start from the LargeArrayScan example in the SDK, that will give you just the prescan. Assuming you have the selection array in device memory (an array of 1 and 0 meaning 1- select 0 - discard), **dev_selection_array** a **dev_elements_array** elements to be selected a **dev_prescan_array** and a **dev_result_array** all of size **N** then you do

```
prescan(dev_prescan_array,dev_selection_array, N);
scatter(dev_result_array, dev_prescan_array,
         dev_selection_array, dev_elements_array, N);
```

where the scatter is

```
 __global__ void scatter_kernel( T*dev_result_array, 
                   const T* dev_prescan_array, 
                   const T* dev_selection_array,
                   const T* dev_elements_array, std::size_t size){

unsigned int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
if (idx >= size) return;
if (dev_selection_array[idx] == 1){
    dev_result_array[dev_prescan_array[idx]] = dev_elements_array[idx];
}
}
```

for other nice application of the prescan see the paper [Ble93](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~blelloch/papers/Ble93.pdf)

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about classic stream compaction. Generally I would recommend looking at [Thrust](http://thrust.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.0/doc/html/group__stream__compaction.html) or [CUDPP](http://www.gpgpu.org/static/developer/cudpp/rel/cudpp_1.1/html/group__public_interface.html#g275bcc2d5cb5b0277027140aae9c51bd) (those links go to the compaction documentation). Both of these are open source, if you want to roll your own then I would also suggest looking at the 'scan' SDK sample.